# Proftpd: How to set default root to a users home directory without jailing the user?

Tags: ftp, chroot, proftpd

I've installed proftpd on my debian box but I'm having having some trouble with the configuration.

In my proftpd.conf I've added;

```
DefaultRoot ~ !ftp_special
```

This works fine in that all users except members of ftp-special are unable to navigate outside of their home folder. However, I want users that are members of **ftp-special** to enter a special home folder when logging on to the ftp server but at the same time I want them to be able to navigate the entire server.

Right now, if a user that is a member of ftp-special logs on, his entry-point is the root ( / ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate any feedback and other suggestions if what I have outlined in my question is impossible.

Comment: What about changing his home in the passwd to the given directory you want them to root in removing the !ftp_special which will root them to the dir you want them to be and aswell allow them access to navigate around if they have access to it within your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe there is no server-side workaround for this. Users who are exempted from the "DefaultRoot" parameter are not forced by the ProFTPd daemon to be logged into a special directory. The only option that I am aware of is to ask the User to set the path on the client-side.

Answer (score 2):

You might try the following:

```
DefaultRoot ~ !ftp_special
DefaultChdir /path/to/specialdir ftp_special
```

The `DefaultChdir` directive will change the initial/default directory for the logging-in user, just like `DefaultRoot`, only without the `chroot()`.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I am aware of only solution where you should change home directories of members of group ftp-special. Maybe there is some mod for proftpd which changes current directory after login.